# Unable to stop DNS leak when connecting to VPN in Lubuntu 17.04

Tags: dns, vpn, openvpn, resolv.conf, resolvconf

Checking doileak.com I always get a DNS server leak on my VPN.

All of the hints that I could find say that the DNS servers are **only** configured through `/etc/resolv.conf`. The expressvpn software as well as when connecting with OpenVPN have the same issue. They both edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` successfully. So there must be another way that my computer gets this DNS.

I've also disable `media.peerconnection.enable` and `geo.enable` in Firefox as suggested in other places. The connection through my router works without a DNS leak from an Android phone, so the problem should be somewhere on the computer side.

Has anyone else had this problem and knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

After plenty of Googling I seem to have found an answer [here](https://airvpn.org/topic/22715-leaking-dns-with-ubuntu-1704/).

Since Ubuntu 17 `NetworkManager` frequently overwrites the `resolv.conf`, leading to DNS leaks. You can avoid this by editing `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. You have to add `dns=none` under the `[main]` section.

Additionally clear the `etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` file from which `resolv.conf` is restored regularly.

Restart your system, and the DNS leak should be gone.